# Can we fix and prevent duplicates without links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find that, nearly always, when google lands me on a SO page and I see the question closed as duplicate (often by many people), there are NO links to the duplicate questions.  It is no use to suggest checking the duplicates if they can't be found.

Could we do four things to fix this?

1) Automatically remove "marked as duplicate" and "closed as duplicate" from ALL questions on SO that have NO links to the actual duplicate.  They can be marked duplicate again when an actual link is provided.

2) Revoke the ability to "mark as duplicate" from anyone who has abused it by marking duplicate without providing a link.  Possibly do this by removing enough reputation so that the existing system would disallow the ability to mark as duplicate.  This should be strong disincentive for the rampant abuse we have been seeing.

3) Make it impossible to "close as duplicate" when no link(s) to the duplicate(s) have been provided.  An accusation of duplicate is not sufficient.  Prove it by providing a link, with the side benefit that people can find the duplicate.

4) Allow the general community to vote on whether the duplicate really is a duplicate (often it's not, and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for countering overzealous/myopic folks claiming "duplicate" at the drop of a hat).  This gives the community a much needed veto.

This should dramatically improve the usefulness of SO by allowing navigation to the better answers, and by penalizing those who would shut down useful questions without providing access to the better answers.

The point is to consider the user's experience.  When I find good answers to my questions, I love SO and keep coming back and recommending SO to others.

On the flip side, when I find my question has been asked, but the answers got shut down by a bunch of people claiming it's a duplicate with no link to the original, that's a different story.  Then it's frustrating that something potentially useful is broken by folks who appear to care more about legalistic technicalities than having SO be actually useful and helpful.

I imagine those marking duplicate feel they're helping.  But when that's done without links, it feels like they just being a-holes. 
 (I know they're not.  This isn't name calling or a personal attack; I'm just saying how it feels.)

Comment: Marking something as a duplicate *requires* a link to do so. you literally can't mark something as a duplicate without the duplicate existing and being linked in the question itself via the "this is closed as a duplicate" banner.

Comment: Such a question starts with a big yellow box stating "This question already has an answer here:" followed by a link. Have you missed that? Do you have an example of a question without such link?

Comment: So... 3) is already done, which means that 2) is moot.... And since 3 is done, 1) isn't needed either .. as for 4.... It's already done. With reopen votes.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrice.  I didn't see any "reopen vote" option.  How does one use that?

Comment: [You need 3K rep to see it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @Tom, happily, no I can't find an example any more.

Comment: Thanks, @Makoto.  That's certainly better than nothing, but above 3k is hardly "the community".  When something is abused by those with high rep, what recourse do the unwashed masses have for fixing it?   Feels like the foxes are guarding the henhouse.

Comment: Quantify "abuse".  It's fine to disagree.  It's quite *another* to call it abuse.

Comment: @Makoto, the correct use for "mark duplicate" is for marking which things are, in fact, dupliacetes, which is a good and important feature.  But when objectively different things are marked as duplicates, that is an incorrect use ("abuse") of the feature.

Comment: The accusation of abuse likely comes from the misunderstanding of what duplication actually *means*.  It doesn't mean the asker will have an answer that meets their exact specifications, and can just copy and paste code and keep going.  It means the core issue is the same, and solving that is in the original.  The asker of the duplicate will likely need to read *and* understand it, and then implement it.  It'll take work, sure, but coding is a lifelong learning process.

Comment: @Makoto, for example, if two people ask whether the sign bit means positive or negative on an IEEE-754 double, that's truly a duplicate.  But If one questions asks that an the other asks what to do with the sign bit in a NaN in an IEEE-754 double, those are objectively different.  When (often the same) 5 or 6 people mark that as a duplicate, they are abusing the "mark duplicate" feature.  I've seen this happen many times, and it really bothers me, especially when there's nothing that  an ordinary user can do about it.

Comment: That likely gets to the "core issue" rationale for closing a question as a duplicate which @fbueckert alludes to above.

Comment: @Makoto, I'm not talking about cutting and pasting homework.  I'm talking about taking two separate things (say, template specialization and template instantiation in c++) and marking them duplicate because they both have the word "template".  Those are two legitimate and totally separate questions, and by shutting one of them down incorrectly, the quality of SO is compromised.

Comment: Note: it takes *expertise* to identify issues that are similar.  That expertise is the very reason people ask questions here in the first place.  Unfortunately, that expertise is discarded as invalid when the duplicate is not understood by those asking for help.  What good is asking for help when that help is discarded?  Be careful what you wish for; you might just get it.

Comment: @fbueckert, I'm sure there are cases where expertise helps.  But having rep is not the same as having expertise.  I've seen too many cases where a small gang of people with rep marked a whole bunch of c++ questions as duplicate when, in point of fact, they were not duplicate.  People correctly pointed out that the duplicate wasn't correct, and yet the questions were closed anyway.  Maybe that just doesn't happen any more, but it did happen, and in those cases I'd be very happy to get what I'm wishing for.  So would the others who correctly pointed out that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Everyone keeps asking you for evidence.  Where are these, "gangs"?  What questions have they closed wrongly?  Who has protested those closures?  Are you *absolutely* sure it's incorrect; you haven't shown a good understanding of the closure system so far, so that understanding isn't a given.  It's almost a certainty that misunderstanding is the core issue here.  I'd recommend re-reading my comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389742/can-we-fix-and-prevent-duplicates-without-links#comment729848_389742)

Comment: When something provably different is marked duplicate by multiple people, that's abuse.  I'm not saying this is common.  This may be the rarest of things.   But do you honestly believe that this has NEVER happened?

Comment: Oh, I'm sure it *has* happened.  I doubt it's at as common as you seem to think.  But you keep asserting that this happens, apparently commonly, by, "gangs".  Where's your proof?  Show us some questions that have been wrongly closed.  We have *so many* people say this, and very few ever bring anything concrete to the table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is referring to cases where the dupe notice has been removed. That's possible on questions closed at least around 2010 (I don't have an exact time frame, but this was in the time where Community edited in duplicate notices instead of it being a post element). @user3670102: If this is the case, you can tell from the post history. It also isn't something we can fix, but you could ask your friendly neighborhood hammer to fix the links by reopening and closing the question.

Answer (score 12):

I want to call this particular bullet point out.

> 4) Allow the general community to vote on whether the duplicate really
>   is a duplicate (often it's not, and there doesn't seem to be a
>   mechanism for countering overzealous/myopic folks claiming "duplicate"
>   at the drop of a hat). This gives the community a much needed veto.

Unqualified and entirely uncalled-for characterization ***aside***, the community already *can* vote on if a question really is a duplicate in the form of reopen votes.  If 5 people believe that the question isn't a duplicate of the linked question(s), then it's likely that it'll be reopened.

Even *faster* is that it can only take one person with a gold badge in a tag to reopen a question if they feel like the dupe(s) aren't suitable enough, or that the question isn't a dupe.

So...what you're looking for is already built into the system, unless you have exact examples of where this hasn't happened.  There are some old-style duplicate questions out there which embedded the links in the question, meaning that they could be edited out (the system wasn't going to prevent it), and I'm wondering if that's what you ran into.

Comment: @Script47:  ...which is why I put it aside. ;)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't say that right, and it's certainly not fair to smear everyone who has high rep, or the folks who correctly mark duplicates, which is a good and important service.  But when half a dozen people INCORRECTLY mark duplicate, that's overzealous and nearsighted.  And the few that do it regularly appear to enjoy doing it and leaving snarky comments.  That's not providing a useful service or providing a good user experience for the benefit of the user and of SO.

Comment: You'll need to prove that those questions were actually closed with malicious intent.  Your insistence on this characterization is not constructive and I wish for it to stop.

Comment: @user3670102 not to be dismissive .... Do you have a single 'abusive' example? Cause you keep on saying there are some ... But I can't say I've seen one... So... Care to show some examples? It's easy to throw 'abuse' around. But if there's no proof, it's..... Not much :/

Comment: Ok, gentelemen.  I apologize.  I can't read the minds or feelings of those marking duplicate incorrectly.  I have no idea what their intent actually is.   So my inappropriate characterizations aside, the problem is that when distinct things are incorrectly marked duplicate, there appears to be no recourse to anyone with less than 3000 rep (what percentage of SO users have 3000 or above?).

Comment: There is...you can always come to Meta to discuss the specific question.  There's even the [meta-tag:specific-question] tag to use for those.  However, to an earlier point made, it does require expertise to see how two seemingly unrelated questions could be considered dupes.  We're all human and we all err on occasion, so coming to us without any prejudice would be **in all of our best interests**.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.   Also, I agree that it does take expertise.  The problem is that having rep is different than having experience, and in some particularly aggravating cases, those marking duplicate either didn't have the expertise, or they didn't read/understand the questions.  They just marked with duplicate and agreed with each other, even though the community correctly pointed out that those weren't duplicates, and why they weren't duplicates.

Comment: @user3670102 again, care to point out examples? a) the meta crew can help either correct the assumptions made in the (maybe wrong?) calling of "this isn't a dupe". b) if not, they can help *fix* the wrong duplicate.  And, saying "people didn't understand the question" is as negative as "abuse". You're basically saying curators are too dumb to know what they're doing. There's no reason to be negative towards whatever other user.

Comment: @Patrice While I agree with all the points being made I'd like to point out that there is the possibility of something having been "robo-reviewed" as being the cause of what the OP of the question claims to have seen... So it can't be dismissed out-of-hand that it has happened. But then such instances should be put forward as links, yes.

Answer (score 9):

> I find that, nearly always, when google lands me on a SO page and I see the question closed as duplicate (often by many people), there are NO links to the duplicate questions

Duplicate-closed questions always have a banner on top of them that link to the duplicate target(s):

> [image]

Without those targets, a question can't be closed as a duplicate.

That makes the rest of this question / suggestion moot.

Comment: These might be the older style questions which could totally have had those duplicate links edited out.

Comment: That could be possible, but those are relatively rare nowadays... Hardly _"nearly always"_

Comment: Ok.  Fair enough.  "nearly always in my experience."  I don't claim to have  a complete picture of the current state of things.

Comment: Can you link us to some examples, @user3670102?

Comment: Well, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266727/generate-xml-schema-from-multiple-xml-files for example.  There are 5 people claiming it's a duplicate, but there's only 1 link given.  Where are the other 4 links?  If there really are 5 better answers, why hide them?  And if there's only 1 better answer, why allow what amounts to "me too" on marknig duplicate?  I thought "me too" was discouraged?

Comment: It doesn't mean there are 5 separate posts. It means that 5 people agree that this post is *a* dupe. It seems that you've misunderstood how dupes work completely.

Comment: Also, I don't think suggestion #4 is moot.  Let's say the community wants to contest whether something truly is a duplicate.  I'm not seeing a way to do that.

Comment: @user3670102:  I provide that angle in my answer.

Comment: Additionally, @user3670102, the question you link to as an example has two quirks to it. First, according to the hover text, that was the original author to approved the duplicate vote, and the system closed it on their behalf.  Second, that *kind* of question - "what tools exist for X" - is generally off-topic for Stack Overflow and wouldn't be permissible today.

Comment: @user3670102 There aren't 5 people there claiming it was a dupe, there was only one person and OP agreed (hence the "community" account listed as one of the closers).

Comment: @Tom there's not much point in writing all this about 1 post.  Yes, that one doesn't have 5 people claiming dupe, and the OP agreed that it was a dupe.  But over the years, I have seen 5 or 6 people (often the same group of people) incorrectly marking duplicate.  If that simply no longer happens, then I'm thrilled, and there's really nothing else to discuss here.

Comment: @user3670102 When you often see the same names in a close reason it can be because these people consistently read (and probably frequently answer) in that particular tag (subject). Because of that, they'd usually have a good idea what has already been asked, and what covers the same ground as a new question requests...

Comment: ...When you find something closed as a duplicate and can objectively point out how it's *not*, please do come here, to Meta, and ask. As you've seen, people here *do listen* and are open to discussing and taking action. Everyone who helps out on Stack Overflow is human, so mistakes are possible. We want the site to have the best quality possible - we're quite passionate about that, to be honest :-) It's very difficult for us to deal with being accused regularly of being "abusive" (and other things) and misunderstandings that are presented so aggressively.